# Why are my design layout editor and emulator look so different?

Tags: xml, android-layout, android-studio

I need help figuring out why my layout editor and design view look so 
[different](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIJbU.png)

Here is the xml [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0chHI.png) that goes with the custom layout in question.
The layout is supposed to be like a pop up menu.

Comment: Because it's a dialog, I'm guessing

Comment: Don't post code in images.

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly set the dimensions for a dialog otherwise it'll compress the blank spaces. So specify it as following:-

`ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = yourDialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
params.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT; 
params.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT; 
// or a value specified in dimensions like R.dimen.custom_width`